# How to use LLVM to programatically compile C source files

Tags: c, clang, llvm, jit

My program (written in C) dynamically generates and compiles many C source files into shared libraries (.so files) by programmatically executing C compiler (clang) command using `system()` function. The compiled .so files are then loaded to the program using `dlopen()`. You can consider it as a naive JIT compiler. The idea is borrowed from page 5 of [this presentation](https://lpc.events/event/7/contributions/732/attachments/507/952/The-LightWeight-JIT-Compiler-Slides.pdf).

The time to generate to disk and compile my C source file ranges from 50 to 100ms. AFAIK, executing external program via `system()` has an overhead and clang also has startup overhead. My idea of reducing overhead is using LLVM as a library to compile C source files. But I have no experience with LLVM library.

My question is: How can I replicate the command `clang -O3 -shared <other options> <source file>.c -o <binary file>.so` using LLVM library?

Comment: Just copy the compiler driver from inside clang. Around a thousand lines of code IIRC, and you're likely to get a 3-5% speedup, or less.